# For custom directive, watch attribute only if expression is passed.

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive that watches a attribute passed in, but for that attribute, a raw string value or a  expression can be passed. If a expression is passed then I need to watch it. But if a raw string is passed then I really don't need to watch the attribute. I'm wondering if there is a standard way to optionally watch attribute based on if a expression is passed versus a string? I can check for "{{*}}" in the attrs but not sure if that's complete.

The directive simply does this:

```
//my-drct.js
 scope.watch( function(){attrs.specialProperty;} , function(value){ 
   controller.update(value); 
 })
```

and my-drct can be used like so:

```
<div my-drct = '{{foo}}'> //need to watch
//or
<div my-drct = 'foo' >  //dont need to watch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse)** service for that.
The parsed expression has a `constant` property (boolean), which indicates if the expression is made up by constant parts (so it will stay the same forever) or if it has some dynamic parts as well.

E.g.:

```
.directive('myDrct', function ($parse) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function myDrctPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var isConstant = $parse(attrs.myDrct).constant;

            if (isConstant) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/rp3Fm/)**.